# Fermat's Little Theorem for composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In Fermat's Little Theorem we have that for a prime number $p$, $a^p \equiv a\pmod{p}$, is this ever true when $p$ is not a prime number, i.e. take some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, would it hold true that $a^n \equiv a\pmod{n}$? Obviously here we assume $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Comment: Yes, look for Carmichael numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: $a=1$ gives lots of trivial examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are non-Carmichael examples as well.  For instance $6^{35}\equiv 6 \pmod{35}$